# Passing Conexion String to VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have always found you a great help when I have questions. This time it's something related to Excel VBA.

I have a macro that brings back data from a website. You simply have to hard code the connection string into it.( xmlHttp.Open "GET", **"http://www.example.com"**, False )

```
Sub GET_HTML_DATA()

    Dim xmlHttp As Object
    Dim TR_col As Object, TR As Object
    Dim TD_col As Object, TD As Object
    Dim row As Long, col As Long

    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    xmlHttp.Open "GET", "http://www.example.com", False
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    xmlHttp.send

    Dim html As Object
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText

    Dim tbl As Object
    Set tbl = html.getElementById("curr_table")

    row = 1
    col = 1

    Set TR_col = html.getElementsByTagName("TR")
    For Each TR In TR_col
        Set TD_col = TR.getElementsByTagName("TD")
        For Each TD In TD_col
            Cells(row, col) = TD.innerText
            col = col + 1
        Next
        col = 1
        row = row + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

I was wondering if and how can this code be changed to accept a parameter as the connection string so I can call on it  **Run "GET_HTML_DATA(parameter)"**

I have tried to declare a parameter in the parenthesis and include that in place of www.example.com but when I run the macro it tells me  **The macro may not be available in this workbook..."**

Am I doing it right or is there another way I do not know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sub in the parenthesis you need to declare the parameter as (input As String) and then use "input" in your code. Then you can use that  Run "GET_HTML_DATA(parameter)". Alternatively, I guess you can simply put all your code in a simple function if you would have to return some output like

```
    Function myFunction(input As String) As Double
        //code goes here
    End Function
```

Comment: Tried to add a variable between the brackets and replace the (xmlHttp.Open "GET", "http://www.example.com", False) to (xmlHttp.Open "GET", link , False) but it does not seem to work. Any other ideeas?

Comment: You need to do Sub GET_HTML_DATA(variable_name as String) and then when you call the sub  - Run "GET_HTML_DATA(parameter)"